# Does Perl 6 have an equivalent to Python's update method on dictionary?

Tags: raku

In Python, if I update the `dict` dictionary with another dict called `u`(use `Perl` as key), it will update the value:

```
>>> dict = {'Python':'2', 'Perl' : 5}
>>> u = {'Perl' : 6}
>>> dict.update(u)
>>> dict
{'Python': '2', 'Perl': 6}
```

but in Perl 6 :

```
> my %hash = 'Python' => 2, Perl => 5;
> my %u = Perl => 6
> %hash.append(%u)
{Perl => [5 6], Python => 2}
```

So, Does Perl 6 have an equivalent to Python's update method on dictionary?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `,` operator to do the update:

```
my %u = Perl => 6;
my %hash = 'Python' => 2, Perl => 5;
%hash = %hash, %u;
say %hash;   # => {Perl => 6, Python => 2}
```

And of course you can shorten the updating line to

```
%hash ,= %u;
```

Answer (score 10):

In Perl 6, one option is to use a [hash slice](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash):

```
my %u = (Perl => 6);
%hash{%u.keys} = %u.values;
```

**Result**:

```
{Perl => 6, Python => 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

And if you don't like either of those, roll your own...

```
sub infix:<Update>(%h , %u) { %h{ %u.keys } = %u.values }

my %hash  = Python => 2, Perl => 5;
my %u = Perl => 6 , Rust => 4.5 ;

%hash Update %u ;
say "After: %hash.perl()" ;    # After: {:Perl(6), :Python(2), :Rust(4.5)}
```

You can also augment the Global hash type;

```
augment class Hash {
    method update(%u) { self{ %u.keys } = %u.values }
}

%hash  = Python => 2, Perl => 5;
%u = Perl => 6 , Rust => 4.5 ;

%hash.update: %u ;
say "After: %hash.perl()" ;    # After: {:Perl(6), :Python(2), :Rust(4.5)}
```

..but, as this is perhaps the ultimate in action at a distance, you have to acknowledge that you know what you're doing through the indignity of placing `use MONKEY-TYPING` at the top of your program